# How do I set up jsr223 scripting with scala as scripting language

Tags: java, scala, scripting-language, jsr223

So far I have tried the sling implementation for jsr223 scripting for scala, but was not able to get it set up correctly.
 when I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala").
          eval("object HelloWorld {def main(args: Array[String]) { 
                  println(\"Hello, world!\") }}");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I got nothing but:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ERROR 
org.apache.sling.scripting.scala.Script line 13 : not found: type 
Script at org.apache.sling.scripting.scala.ScalaScriptEngine.eval(ScalaScriptEngine.scala:117)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
```

similar Problems are discussed here:
http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/How-to-compile-Scala-code-from-java-using-the-current-ClassLoader-instead-of-a-string-based-classpat-td1955873.html#a1955873

and

http://dev.day.com/discussion-groups/content/lists/sling-dev/2009-12/2009-12-01_Scala_scripting_support_was_Re_And_another_one____Michael_D_rig.html

maybe there is another Implementation that I'm not aware of.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the test cases in the scala/script module of [Apache Sling](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/contrib/scripting/scala/script/src/test/scala/org/apache/sling/scripting/scala/ScriptEngineTest.scala) for a working example. The script and its entry point (that is the object) need to follow certain conventions. I'll provide more information on these if required later.

For a general overview of the scripting engine see [my session slides from Scala Days 2010](http://people.apache.org/~mduerig/scala4scripting/scala4scripting1.pdf).

**Update:** Scripts must be of the following form:

```
package my.cool.script {
  class foo(args: fooArgs) {
    import args._ // import the bindings
    println("bar:" + bar)
  }
}
```

The type of `args` is [generated by the script engine](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1236) and is named after the simple class name of the script appended with 'Args'. Further the example assumes, that the [Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/Bindings.html) passed for script evaluation contains a value for the name 'bar'. For further details see the class comment on [`ScalaScriptEngine`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/contrib/scripting/scala/script/src/main/scala/org/apache/sling/scripting/scala/ScalaScriptEngine.scala).

You need to pass the name of your script class to the script engine. You do this by putting the fully qualified script name (i.e. `my.cool.script.foo`) into the [`ScriptContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html) by the name 'scala.script.class'.

Answer (score 4):

With the conclusion of https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-874 in version 2.11, it should be as easy as what is shown in the ticket:

```
import javax.script.*;
ScriptEngine e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");
e.getContext().setAttribute("label", new Integer(4), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
try {
    engine.eval("println(2+label)");
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: With the current Scala Version 2.11.0-M4 there need to be done some extra work to configure the environment to use the java classpath: ... List nil = Nil$.MODULE$; $colon$colon vals = $colon$colon$.MODULE$.apply((String) "true", nil); ((IMain)engine).settings().usejavacp().tryToSet(vals);

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my comment was unreadable without linebreaks - so...

To be able to run the Codesnippet mentioned I needed to make the following changes.
I used Scala 2.11.0-M4

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");

  // Set up Scriptenvironment to use the Java classpath
  List nil = Nil$.MODULE$;
  $colon$colon vals = $colon$colon$.MODULE$.apply((String) "true", nil);
  ((IMain)engine).settings().usejavacp().tryToSet(vals);ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

  engine.getContext().setAttribute("labelO", new Integer(4), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
  try {
    engine.eval("val label = labelO.asInstanceOf[Integer]\n"+
                "println(\"ergebnis: \" + (2 + label ))");
  } catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: remark: current Milestone 2.11.0-M5 has an error and returns NULL for getEngineByName("scala") https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7843 M6 should work (I have not tested)