# JSR-223 Scala Script Engine

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to use Scala as a script language, that will be called from java and after that I need to get some objects as a result of script execution.

I tried to find a good interpretor that can do what i need but unsuccesfull. Is the exists an implementation of JSR-223 for Scala? Or may be someone know how to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654888/how-do-i-set-up-jsr223-scripting-with-scala-as-scripting-language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Official support in scala starts in version 2.11 as seen in this closed ticket: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-874

Answer (score 3):

This library: http://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/
may help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run the Codesnippet mentioned in ([How do I set up jsr223 scripting with scala as scripting language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654888/how-do-i-set-up-jsr223-scripting-with-scala-as-scripting-language)) I needed to make the following changes.
I used Scala 2.11.0-M4

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");

  // Set up Scriptenvironment to use the Java classpath
  List nil = Nil$.MODULE$;
  $colon$colon vals = $colon$colon$.MODULE$.apply((String) "true", nil);
  ((IMain)engine).settings().usejavacp().tryToSet(vals);ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

  engine.getContext().setAttribute("labelO", new Integer(4), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
  try {
    engine.eval("val label = labelO.asInstanceOf[Integer]\n"+
                "println(\"ergebnis: \" + (2 + label ))");
  } catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solid [ScriptingEngine implementation](https://github.com/apache/clerezza/tree/master/scala-scripting)

Comment: The link gives 404 currently.