# Scala Function block as String to Function

Tags: string, function, scala

Just wondering if there is a any way to convert/parse a string, containg a Scala function body block, to a Function object.

Comment: Do you mean runtime, or compiletime? For the first, probably a [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209995/jsr-223-scala-script-engine), for the latter, [quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html) with macros.

Comment: I ment runtime, since I want to receive an expression from an input string, and make it an executable function.

Comment: Please see the Scala REPL. https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.11.x/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`Eval`](https://github.com/twitter/util#eval) class from Twitter. This previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10/12123609) might also be of use.